# Largest number of students who can attend special lesson

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

A teacher provides four special lessons, one each in Maths, Music,
English and Science, for some of the children in her class. For the
students in these special lessons:
• there are exactly 3 children in each lesson.
• each pair of students attends at least one special lesson together.
What is the largest number of students who can attend these special
lessons?

Can someone help me solve this problem?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is expected that you show your working to show how far you have got in solving the problem by yourself. Please, if you can, edit your question with any ideas you have, no matter how small. Then people can see how stuck you are, and on which parts. Do this in the body of the question and don't leave it for the comment section.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the number of possible pairs in the lessons, each class has $3$ pairs and the there are $4$ classes, so that makes $12$ possible pairs.

If there are $5$ students there are $10$ pairs, if there are $6$ students there are $15$ pairs (too many!), so the largest number of students is possibly $5$, now can all $10$ pairs be realised in the four classes ...

The answer is yes ...

> $\{a,b,c \},\{a,d,e\},\{b,c,d\},\{b,c,e\} $

Answer (score 0):

With six kids, there are $\binom62=15$ different pairs. Each lesson hosts $\binom32=3$ pairs, and there are only four lessons, so at least three pairs will never meet. Therefore, six is too many.

Can you make it happen with five? Try to build a complete graph on five vertices, i.e., a pentagon with a star inscribed, out of four triangles, overlapping allowed (indeed, necessary).